# Change font size in NativeBase theme for input component

Tags: react-native, input, themes, native-base

I use NativeBase [Input Component](https://docs.nativebase.io/input) and [Costume Theme](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-theme), I tried to change the font size of the input component in my costume theme I already tried to change it in the following examples, but it doesn't change.

How can I change the font size of the input component in my costume theme?

Example 1:

```
const themeOne = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: {
        style: { color: "white", fontSize: "20" },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Example 2:

```
const themeOne = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: {
        style: { color: "white"},
        fontSize: "20",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `defaultProps`. Read more about [customizing Input component](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/v3.1.0/src/theme/components/input.ts).

```
const theme = extendTheme({
    components: {
      Input: {
        baseStyle: {
          color: 'red.400',
        },
        defaultProps: { size: '2xl' },
      },
    },
  });
```